# Can Spring boot create an application.properties template

Tags: java, spring-boot

We've created a Spring Boot application with some property sources configuring the modules of application. Now it comes to document configuration of the application. Instead of writing a separate document I'd like to document in code and create documentation.

First naiv approach would be to write property files like this and then generate a default `application.properties` (or yaml) to be adapted by end user:

```
a.b.c.myProperty=42
a.b.c.myProperty.desc=This is the documentation for myProperty
a.b.c.foo=baa
a.b.c.foo.desc=foo is the most important parameter ever!
```

Before reinventing the wheel, is there already some way to create configuration documentation out of my property sources?